How find out a process piping into another process?
I have long running process which is reading from STDIN. However I am not sure which process is piping data into it. The process creation is handled by a process manager and I have no control over it. I tried using lsof to figure it out, but I could not.
What would be a standard way to figure the process-id of the piping process?

Why do you need to know? What are you doing with that information?

why not lsof ?

@DiegoTorresMilano lsof is giving me the pipe device id. But  not other process is matching it.

This will give you what you want
pid=<THEPIDYOUWANT>; lsof | grep "$(lsof -nPFti -p $pid | grep -A1 tFIFO | sed -En 's/^i(.*)$/\1/p')"

the list of processes using the pipe will appear and from FD you can tell which one reads or writes.
